# Homebrew says I have macvim installed

Tags: vim, macvim

I haven't used macvim in a while, and not sure how to get it running.

Homebrew says I have version 7.3.64 installed, yet I can't seem to find it in 'finder' or the command line.

How do I get it running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One additional step is required when you install a GUI app through homebrew. 
It briefly mentions this during the install process, but it is easy to miss.

```
brew install macvim
==> Downloading https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/archive/snapshot-70.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --with-macarchs=x86_64 --enable-perlinterp --enable-rubyinterp --enable-tclinterp --with-ruby-c
==> make
==> Caveats
MacVim.app installed to:
  /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-70

To link the application to a normal Mac OS X location:
    brew linkapps
or:
    ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-70/MacVim.app /Applications
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-70: 1796 files, 28M, built in 2.2 minutes
```

---

To fix this, run the command that creates the symbolic link

```
 ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-70/MacVim.app /Applications
```

or run to link all apps in brew

```
 brew linkapps
```

Then look in `/Applications`, you will see an icon for MacVim

If you want to start MacVim from the command line, run the following

```
open /Applications/MacVim
```

Comment: To see the Caveats of already installed homebrew formulae you can use `brew info [formula]` so `brew info macvim` would show that hint on linking GUI apps into /Applications

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply download it and install it like any other application.